# Unresolved namespace UnityEngine.VR.WSA

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a networked Unity project using HLAPI from which I need to build:

- A Hololens client (platform = WSA)
- A Windows desktop client (platform = PC standalone)
- A Windows desktop server (platform = PC standalone)

I have three specialized scenes, one for each of these roles, and a base scene that only loads one of them at run-time depending on a role setting.

Here is the problem from there. I have scripts, **including the HoloToolkit from Microsoft**, referenced in the Hololens client scene using classes in namespaces `UnityEngine.VR.WSA` and `UnityEngine.VR.WSA.Ipnut`. That compiles just fine for the WSA platform. But, when the time comes to build the desktop client and the desktop server, all those scripts fail to compile as if those namespaces did not exist.

Here is an example:

```
Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Scripts/GestureManager.cs(139,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GestureRecognizer' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

`GestureRecognizer` is in `UnityEngine.VR.WSA.Input`. I would have thought that the backend would be smart enough to simply throw NotSupported exceptions at run-time if any class in those namespaces would be called under PC standalone platform (and I am smart enough not to call anything from them when role = desktop client or desktop server) but it simply does not compile so I am really stuck. Does anyone know any solution to this without rewriting everything with `UNITY_WSA` or `UNITY_STANDALONE` preprocessor flags to insert everywhere even in 3rd party imported assets?

I was on Unity 5.4 beta for Hololens and this was no problem, at all. Then I migrated to 5.6 and this became one.

Answer (score 1):

You should have considered this even before making your app. Some APIs are not available between Windows standalone and Windows Store build. It's even worst wne Hololens is involved.

Your example of why preprocessor solution is not acceptable is not good.
Preprocessor directive is the way to solve this. You don't have to wrap it around the place the `class` is declared. Just wrap it around the places you imported the name space. For example,

```
#if UNITY_WSA
    using UnityEngine.VR.WSA;
#endif
```

Also, to make this really easy for you, you should **not** access the API from the `UnityEngine.VR.WSA` namespace directly from your other classes.

Build a wrapper class that wraps around all those input from the `UnityEngine.VR.WSA` namespace then then use  `#if UNITY_WSA` inside that class. By doing this, you will only need to have `#if UNITY_WSA` in one class instead of all the classes that reference any API from the `UnityEngine.VR.WSA` namespace.

It is easier to manage. To access the inputs from the `UnityEngine.VR.WSA` namespace, you use that wrapper. Remember to only wrap around the API's that you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do understand your suggestion to gather everything under a single wrapper class but I should not do it with the HoloToolkit, if you are familiar with Hololens, or anything else not yet added in. I have been avoiding this possibility but maybe the project itself should be broken down into many sub projects. One platform per sub project and this question would be done. In fact, I tried it already using Unity HLAPI; assets from different projects are a mess to handle. The HLAPI seems to me intended for a single project. But maybe using Unity LLAPI...

Comment: You can do one platform per sub project that's even worse because you have to make your code look the-same. If you fix one bug on one project, you have to fix another one in another project. How long will it be before it becomes unmanageable. If you don't want to use a wrapper, that's fine. Just use `#if UNITY_WSA` mentioned above inside functions, imports and variable declaration. That should work.